# What is the difference about effect and reducer in flutter redux

Tags: flutter

I am now using flutter redux (fish redux) to handle the action dispatch, the effect like this:

```
Effect<CruiseSettingState> buildEffect() {
  return combineEffects(<Object, Effect<CruiseSettingState>>{
    CruiseSettingAction.action: _onAction,
  });
}
```

and the reducer like this:

```
Reducer<CruiseSettingState> buildReducer() {
  return asReducer(
    <Object, Reducer<CruiseSettingState>>{
      CruiseSettingAction.action: _onAction,
    },
  );
}
```

Both are react by some action.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference about effect/reducer?
2. Which one I should use when write my app?
3. Why do we need to have 2 concepts and 2 ways of handling one thing?